# Finding singular solution to a Lagrange equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find a singular solution (not general) to the following differential equation:
$$y=3xy'-7y'^3$$
One method for finding a singular solution is called p-discriminant and it consists in solving this system:
$$\cases{F(x,y,y')=0 \\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=0}$$
Where F is the the differential equation. So the system looks like:
$$\cases{y=3xy'-7y'^3 \\y'=\pm \sqrt{\frac{x}{7}}}$$ So if we solve the system we get
$$y=\pm \frac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{7}}$$ On first sight there is nothing wrong but if we differentiate we get that
$$y'=\pm3\sqrt{\frac{x}{7}}=3y'$$ Which doesn't make any sense. Moreover the text book says that the only singular solution is $y=0$ which I have no idea how to conclude using the only the upper method(without guesswork). Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for

$$
\cases{F(x,y,y')=0 \\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=0}
$$

which is $y_e = \pm 2\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{7}}$ gives us an envelope of the possible solutions to the ode but this envelope, in this case, is not a solution to the ode because it doesn't verifies it. An obvious singular solution is $y_s = 0$. Note that a singular solution is also a particular solution but it can't be obtained from the general solution to the ode by specifying the values of the arbitrary constants. Unfortunately in this case it is difficult to reach the closed solution to prove immediately that $y_s=0$ is not obtainable from an adequate choice for the integration constant. Attached a stream plot from one of the three ode solution leaves in blue, and in red $y_e = -2\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{7}}$.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to analytically come to the conclusion that $y=0$ is the singular solution?